# Widgetizing Themes

Tags: wordpress

i want to add plugin into single posts so it looks same as the home page.(ie, all plugins in home page and also in the same place as in home page).
so i decided to follow this Link
this is my functions.php

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * Sueva Theme Functions
 *
 * This is your standard WordPress
 * functions.php file.
 *
 * @author  Alessandro Vellutini
 *
*/

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/core/main.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/core/admin/function_panel.php';

 add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
?>


<?php
/**
 * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas.
 *
 */
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Home right sidebar',
        'id'            => 'home_right_1',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
?>
```

and my sidebar.php

```
<?php if ( novalite_template('span') == "span8" ) : ?>

    <section id="sidebar" class="span4">
        <div class="row">

            <?php if ( is_active_sidebar('side_sidebar_area')) { 

                dynamic_sidebar('side_sidebar_area');

            } else { 

                the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Calendar',
                array("title"=> __('Calendar','wip')),
                    array('before_widget' => '<div class="pin-article span4"><div class="article">',
                          'after_widget'  => '</div></div>',
                          'before_title'  => '<h3 class="title">',
                          'after_title'   => '</h3>'
                    )
                );

                the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Archives','',
                    array('before_widget' => '<div class="pin-article span4"><div class="article">',
                          'after_widget'  => '</div></div>',
                          'before_title'  => '<h3 class="title">',
                          'after_title'   => '</h3>'
                    )
                );

                the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Categories','',
                    array('before_widget' => '<div class="pin-article span4"><div class="article">',
                          'after_widget'  => '</div></div>',
                          'before_title'  => '<h3 class="title">',
                          'after_title'   => '</h3>'
                    )
                );


             } ?>

        </div>
    </section>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'home_right_1' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="primary-sidebar" class="primary-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'home_right_1' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

my theme is nova-lite.

this creates a space for plugins in the bottom of the posts. i want the space to be on the right hand side of the posts (as in home page). how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i solved the problem with using a plugin widget-on pages. 
With this plugin i can place widgets on any posts or page.